# Time Trigger Copy Paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to Google scripts and so far I only have a functional understanding of 'onEdit'. I want to incorporate Google's time triggers however I don't know how to do it due to lack of understanding.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Objective: Create a spreadsheet that keeps track of metrics on a weekly basis

Current Set up: Currently, the spreadsheet uses 'CountIF' on a queried spreadsheet from multiple users to compile all the data and determine the status of every to-do item at any moment.

Need: I would like to set up a script that takes affect every Sunday. The script would copy the metrics from the previous week and paste them into a row below based upon the start date and date date of the previous week (Which are kept in columns A ad B...Ex: 7/7/2018 & 7/14/2018. If the previous week falls into this date range, the cumulative metrics for that week will paste into columns C-L of that week.

Essentially, row 3 would always keep the running total and then the rows below row 3 would populate with a "total to date" for the given date range.

Answer (score 0):

In your Apps Script editor go to **Edit > Current Projects Triggers** and select **Time Driven > Week Timer**.

[image]